# node-hid not showing all USB devices

Tags: node.js, macos, nfc, hid, acr122

I'm using [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/) with this call:

```
HID.devices()
```

and I should get a list of all connected USB devices as [listed here in the guide](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid#get-a-list-of-all-hid-devices-in-the-system).

As result I'm getting this devices list:

```
[ { vendorId: 1452,
  productId: 33346,
  path: 'USB_05ac_8242_6500000',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: 'Apple Computer, Inc.',
  product: 'Apple IR',
  release: 22,
  interface: -1 },
{ vendorId: 1452,
  productId: 567,
  path: 'USB_05ac_0237_6300000',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: 'Apple Inc.',
  product: 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  release: 144,
  interface: -1 },
{ vendorId: 1452,
  productId: 567,
  path: 'USB_05ac_0237_6300000',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: 'Apple Inc.',
  product: 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  release: 144,
  interface: -1 },
{ vendorId: 0,
  productId: 0,
  path: '',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: '',
  product: 'Apple Mikey HID Driver',
  release: 0,
  interface: -1 },
{ vendorId: 1452,
  productId: 567,
  path: 'USB_05ac_0237_6300000',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: 'Apple Inc.',
  product: 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  release: 144,
  interface: -1 },
{ vendorId: 1452,
  productId: 567,
  path: 'USB_05ac_0237_6300000',
  serialNumber: '',
  manufacturer: 'Apple Inc.',
  product: 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  release: 144,
  interface: -1 } ]
```

which does not include the ACR122U-A9 device (NFC/RFID device provided by ACS Ltd) connected through USB to my Mac.

All the peripherals connected to the Mac are listed under `System Report -> Hardware -> USB`, here the screenshot: [image: ACR122U connected to the Mac]

Can you figure out how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

node-hid is a library to access USB HID devices from node.js. `HID.devices()` will therefore only list USB **HID** devices and not just any USB device.

The ACR122U is a **CCID** (USB class for smartcard readers) and not a HID (USB class for human interface devices) device. Consequently, it cannot be listed by node-hid.

Comment: Ok, I get the point. I need to read the data of that reader in JS, do you know how can I achieve this or if there is any library?

Comment: No, I don't know if there's any such library.

Comment: I'm working on a project where I have to connect the ACR123U to nodeJs too.
what I usually do is use C to do the dirty stuff and then communicate whatever I want to nodejs using unix sockets, I can even send JSON string from C to nodejs